# TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments when we use (old='XYZ',new='ABC')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying string replace function by providing arg_name=VALUE but got `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`

`>>>s = "shubham shriavstava"`

`>>>s.replace(old=u"sh", new=u"",count=1)`

> TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just do `s.replace(u"sh", u"", count=1)`

Comment: I know that would work I was curious to know why was providing old=XYZ not working. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is a built-in implemented in C that cannot take keyword arguments. From the [Calls section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> **CPython implementation detail:** An implementation may provide built-in functions whose positional parameters do not have names, even
>   if they are ‘named’ for the purpose of documentation, and which
>   therefore cannot be supplied by keyword.

You can resolve the issue by removing the keywords from your function call.

Answer (score 0):

> **replace(self, old, new, count=-1, /)**
>
> Return a copy with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

Do this:

```
s = "shubham shriavstava"
new_s = s.replace(u"sh", u"", 1) # same to s.replace("sh", "", 1)
print(new_s)
```

> **Output:** 'ubham shriavstava'